# What does Include & Extend correspond to in Programming?

Tags: oop, uml

Just as Generalization in UML corresponds to Inheritance, what do Include & Extend relationships correspond to in OOP?
I do realize that Generalization represents a 'is-a' relationship. Would Include represent 'has-a' relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no include or extend relationships in UML Class Diagrams. If you refer to Use Case Diagrams they have no direct representation on code level, as you do not implement a Use Case as a single artifact in your software.

Comment: Why no direct representation? A use case can be represented as a web service for example.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, **include** used in Use Case diagrams. It shows dependency between specific use case and common use case.

Example:

**Ask question on StackOverflow** *----include---->* **Login to StackOverflow**

Answer (score 0):

Includes means direct dependency, which means that an including use case requires an including use case. Extension means extra functionality that you can add to a use case at a specified point.

An example of include relation is when you include a class in java. You must have the class for your code to execute, but this doesn't mean that you always call the other class.

An example of extends are eclipse extension points, which let you define new functionality for the eclipse platform at specified points, but the platform is unaware of the extensions.